# Imported DMS points from CSV to a point layer. Do I need to convert DMS points to Decimal Degrees to use metric distance units for Buffer?

Tags: qgis, buffer, degrees-minutes-seconds

[image]

DMS - Degrees Minutes Seconds

Buffer tool only shows degrees as the distance unit (not meter or kilometer)

1. Do I need to convert DMS points to Decimal Degrees to use metric
   distance units for Buffer?
2. Is there a plug-in that automatically converts DMS to DD in QGIS?

Or is

Comment: Solved: used UTM 51N CRS

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Decimal degrees will still use geographic degrees as the distance unit in the Buffer processing algorithm.

You can either reproject your layer to a projected coordinate system by right clicking the layer and selecting export --> save features as --> and save it to a vector format such as 
geopackage or shapefile and select a projected CRS appropriate for your zone (e.g. EPSG: 32651). The buffer tool will then use meters as distance unit.

Or, a much quicker and in my opinion, better way would be to create a buffer using a virtual layer.

Go to Layer --> Add layer --> Add/edit virtual layer and use something like this as your query.

```
select st_buffer(st_transform(geometry, 32651), 100) from Calapan_XYpoints
```

Just change the `100` argument to your required buffer distance in meters

Comment: Got that. Thank you!

Comment: @BallpenMan, did you try the virtual layer approach using st_transform with the query I suggested? It negates the need to save and reproject your csv. It will work directly with your delimited text layer in epsg: 4326.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you´re using Geographic coordinates (regardless to the format: DMS or DD).
To solve that, you can: A - **reproject you point Layer** to an Projected CRS through the **Reproject layer** tool available in processing toolbox or 
B - you can **export / save as** your point layer to a new shapefile with a projected CRS.

Note: If you use an UTM Projection, you will be able to perform the buffer specifying distance in meters. Make sure you specify the right zone.

Comment: Really helpful. Thanks!